# Use Variable to insert VALUES bigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

need some help!
I'm trying to set variables in my VALUES statement, but I have no Idea how.

What I need:

```
let abc = 1
let def = 2
let ghi = 3

 const query = `INSERT INTO myTable( abc, def, ghi)
        VALUES ("ABC VARIABLE HERE","DEF VARIABLE HERE"," GHI VARIBALE HERE")`;
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to use Parameterized Queries

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#node.js_3

```
queryString=`INSERT INTO \`MYTABLE\`(abc, def, ghi) 
VALUES ( @abc, @def, @ghi);`;
```

Answer (score 1):

something like that :

```
let abc = 1
let def = 2
let ghi = 3

 const query = FORMAT("INSERT INTO myTable( abc, def, ghi)
        VALUES (%d,%d,%d)",abc,def,ghi);
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your response! I could not use your method in my model because I'm trying to query google BigQuery. Thanks again!

Comment: that is google big query syntax , I don't understand why you couldn't use it

Comment: Hello @eshirvana, I can't use because I got this error:
ReferenceError: FORMAT is not defined
    at query

Comment: that is weird,  here is [google BogQuery doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format_string)